# Communication to activity in stack

Tags: android

Let's consider the following situation:

`Activity A` opens `Activity B`. Now, `A` is in `activity stack`. `B` downloads any data from the Internet and, basing on that data, we conclude that when user come back to the `A` ( after press back) `A` should refresh its content. How to say: `B: Hey A in stack, please remember that you should refresh your content`. I see that I can set some flag in App instance, but, it seems to be weird.

Comment: Option 1: You can pass the data back from B to A in `onBackPressed`. Option 2: Store the data in SharedPreferences and make A read it each time it is loaded. Initially it will be empty so nothing will be done. later B writes to it and when again A is rendered it will get the data and render it accordingly.

Comment: Use the `Activity` life cycle methods to your advantage - look at `onPause()` and `onResume()` - these are where you want your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using **startActivityForResult** in your ActivityA to call ActivityB, then within your ActivityB, override `onBackPressed()` method and call `setResult()` based on downloaded data. Finally back into your ActivityA override `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

Use the following example as guide:

**ActivityA.java**

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (1234 == requestCode) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Do action 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Do action 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

}
```

**ActivityB.java**

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    if (true) {  //Replace this condition by yours based on downloaded data
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    } else {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that way. Always update Activity A content in the `onResume()` method of A activity.